# how to restrict form to load in winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms i.e., `frmLogin` and `frmDash`. I have username and password saved in `credentials.txt` file. My default run form is `frmLogin`. Now my problem is, when application starts it checks username and password from `credentials.txt`and directly shows `frmDash`. Its working, but problem is, with `frmDash` , `frmLogin` is also opening at back. How to solve this?

I have tried this(Form1 is frmLogin):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var credentialLines = File.ReadAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\credentials\\credentials.txt");
                if (credentialLines.Any())
                {
                    UserName_reLogin = credentialLines[0];
                    Password_reLogin = credentialLines[1];
                    if (LoginUser(Log_API, UserName_reLogin, Password_reLogin))
                    {
                        logIn_Status = "true";
                        GlolbalUtil.LogIn_Status = logIn_Status;

                        //this.Hide();

                        frmDash frmDash = new frmDash();
                        frmDash.Owner = this;
                        frmDash.Show();
                        txtUsername.Text = "";
                        txtPassword.Text = "";
                        //GlolbalUtil.accept_status = "1";
                        this.Enabled = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please Check Username and password");

                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    this.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean by outside the frmLogin? this must be in frmLogin as i am getting username and password from .txt file to this form for login

Comment: You are just doing it in the worst possible place.  A common issue with the Load event, if you think you need it then you are probably wrong.  Do it in the caller, whatever code creates this form object.  For a "login" that's usually your Main() method in Program.cs.  And don't create the form when you are not happy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21063756/17034

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private void FrmLogin_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (GlolbalUtil.authenticate == "true")
            {
                this.Hide();
            }
            else if(GlolbalUtil.authenticate == "false")
            {
                this.Show();
            }
        }
```

`GlobalUtil.authenticate` is global variable to check if user is logged in or not. if user is logged in that means `GlobalUtil.authenticate=="true"`, then only `frmLogin` will `hide` otherwise `show`. worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Move to your login logic to  Program.cs in the Main function for something like this

```
var credentialLines = File.ReadAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\credentials\\credentials.txt");
if (credentialLines.Any()){
      UserName_reLogin = credentialLines[0];
      Password_reLogin = credentialLines[1];
if (LoginUser(Log_API, UserName_reLogin, Password_reLogin)){
    Application.Run(new frmDash ());
}else{
Application.Run(new frmlogin());
}
}else
{
Application.Run(new frmlogin());
}
```

Comment: `LoginUser` is method written in `frmLogin.cs` . how can i put this in program.cs

Comment: create new object for frmlogin like this frmlogin f=login=new frmlogin();

Comment: and use login.loginuser()

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should check if the credential exists before opening the login Form.

but anyway to hide forms use `this.Hide();` to hide forms

Comment: right. 
so a good practice will be setting `DialogResults` in the login Form, then `Close();`
so you can check the results back in your main method